# ASP.NET textbox with jQuery UI DatePicker value lost when doing a postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've got an application that uses jQuery UI DatePicker on an ASP.NET textbox control.

The control is working as intended, but I've noticed that when you postback from a server  call (via submit button), the entered value gets lost in the application.

Was wondering if you all have experienced this? What measures that you have to do to prevent this?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCallsMadeFrom" class="field" EnableViewState="true">

var callsMadeFromId = '#<%=txtCallsMadeFrom.ClientID %>';
jQuery(callsMadeFromId).datepicker({ showOn: "button", buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif", altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { } });
```

Comment: i am bit surprised.. i use a datepicker in my application and after reading your question i checked if my textbox holds the date after the postback.. **it does** even after i put `EnableViewState="false"` in the code

Comment: @TheSuperTramp : I can bet on the fact that his control is configured ReadOnly="true", hence the behavior. I just run on the same problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider saving the Textbox's value in a hidden field. I do that with Jquery tabcontrols as they also forget which tab is selected during a postback.

Comment: Thanks Johnny! I'll do this approach. :)

Comment: Sorry, you answer is wrong, I tried make override for onunload() event and then I put the value into the textbox calendar and then the data is lost

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue as well and even after trying to set view state on page or for control it did not workout. The approach to use a hidden field required to me manage sync between date field and the hidden field as the user was playing with the dates. So I decided to set the date again on document.ready as given in the post here, hope this helps.

http://www.himanshusaxena.net/asp-net-text-box-with-jquery-ui-date-picker-value-lost-on-a-post-back/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you haven't put `<%@ Page EnableViewState="false"%>` in .. if you have done so you can still turn on the view state of individual control by `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCallsMadeFrom" class="field" ViewStateMode="Enabled">`

Comment: Thanks @TheSuperTramp! I'll take note of this.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you dont need any jQuery trick.
You have to Remember to ALWAYS send the date to the TextBox in MM/DD/YYYY format in every single postback, dont matter if you work in DD/MM/YYYY.

Solution:

in ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtFechaIni").datepicker();
    $('#txtFechaIni').datepicker('option', { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });            
});
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaIni" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

In codebehind (C#) use the Page_LoadComplete event to transform the date to MM/DD/YYYY in every postback. I use this event because is the last thing that is executed before the Page_Unload and you dont have to transform the date in every event:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtFechaIni.Text.Length == 10)
    {
        //Transform DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY.
        txtFechaIni.Text = txtFechaIni.Text .Substring(3, 2) + "/" + txtFechaIni.Text .Substring(0, 2) + "/" + txtFechaIni.Text .Substring(6, 4)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done. It works in or out of an update panel and retains the value on postback.

```
<script>
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function(evt, args) {
    $("#<%= txtTime.ClientID %>").timepicker({timeformat: 'HH:mm' }); 
    $( "#<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
</script>
```

Here is the partial XAML of my textboxes in the update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" style="margin-left: -4px" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
    //other controls.
    .
    .
    .
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" Width="130px"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" Width="115" ></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I hope this helps others!