# DateTime parsing of TextBox's text raising exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I'm using this script as a date picker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/m/yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'http://192.168.211.71/Imagens/calendar_icon.png'
        });
    });
</script>
```

`$("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({` In this line I assign the date picker to txtDate control (TextBox). The problem arises when I'm trying to add it as a parameter to a stored procedure:

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataPedido", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtDate.Text, "dd/M/yyyy", Nothing)
```

I get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`
`Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

How do I properly parse the value of the textbox to a DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `Nothing` as third parameter to `DateTime.ParseExact` you say: *"use my current culture's date-separator instead of /"*. But actually you want to use the slashes as separator. Therefore you can use `InvariantCulture`:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtDate.Text, "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Another way to mask this special format specifier is to use apostrophes around:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TxtDate.Text, "dd'/'M'/'yyyy", Nothing)
```

Here is the relevant [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. **The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

and in [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is mentioned:

> If provider is null, the **CultureInfo object that corresponds to the
>   current culture is used**.

---

I guess this is an issue with the jQuery-Datepicker control. Have a look here:

[ASP.NET textbox with jQuery UI DatePicker value lost when doing a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255651/asp-net-textbox-with-jquery-ui-datepicker-value-lost-when-doing-a-postback)

Comment: `Cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataPedido", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtDate.Text, "dd/M/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` Still get the same error.

Comment: It's whatever the user picks from the calendar (date picker) script. Example: "02/2/2015"

Comment: @MartimCosta: you can see that it works with both mentioned approaches: `Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact("02/2/2015", "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact("02/2/2015", "dd'/'M'/'yyyy", Nothing)`. Have you used the debugger to see if the value is really `"02/2/2015"`?

Comment: I just ran the debugger and you're right, TxtDate.text = "" even though I can see the date when on the page.

Comment: The text box isn't bound to anything. Where would I add the check? I tried adding it to `txtDate_Load` and `Page_Load` but it did not work.

Comment: You dont need this check it if you don't set it's Text on load anyway. However, i guess this is an issue with the `jQuery`-Datepicker control. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255651/asp-net-textbox-with-jquery-ui-datepicker-value-lost-when-doing-a-postback

Comment: The HiddenField works but I found a better way, I ended up using an input of type text instead of the asp.net TextBox control and this worked, no need for an extra control such as HiddenField.